# шифрование php и windows cmd (powershell)

Tags: php, windows, cmd, powershell

Нужна помощь, существует ли общий инструмент кодирования/декодирования строк для php и консоли windows (cmd/PowerShell)? Поавторитетней с использованием ключа.
Спасибо.

Ситуация следующая. 
Нужно создать файлы для rdp подключения, что бы пользователь не видел пароль. 
Я пробую создать .bat файлы и если пароль хранится в чистом виде, подключение срабатывает, при попытке использования банального base64 все ломается.

```
@echo off
doskey decode64=powershell "[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([convert]::FromBase64String(\"$*\"))"
SET IP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
SET USERNAME=user
SET EncodePass=xxxxx
SET DOMAIN=MYDOMAIN
start cmdkey /generic:"%IP%" /user:"%USERNAME%" /pass: call decode64 %EncodePass%
start mstsc /f /v:"%IP%"
```

В этом случае шифрование base64 на windows и на сервере (php) выдают разные значения. А по хорошему хотелось бы использовать ключ шифрования.

Comment: рнр сожно запускать в повершелл, тащемта

Comment: http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2018/10/18/shifrovanie-paroley-v-skriptah-powershell/ - не оно?